# OpenOlat (LMS) and CMS recomendations?

Tags: content-management-system

my company is considering to use OpenOlat (LMS) in conjunction with a CMS.

The idea ist that our educaters will use OpenOlat as it is, while some functions (like displaying multiple choice tests) will be handled by a CMS. This way we try to keep things simple for our customers...

Problem is that I don´t know much about CMS (an programming in general) since I´am more like an expert on education... and also (aus usual) time ist pressing...

So my question is, if someone has tried this yet and if there are any suggestions which CMS to choose, especialy from a programmer´s perspective...

Comment: USE Liferay for CMS and use Sakai for LMS we are using them in our company most of people are using this combination.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOLAT has a fully embedded testing tool which also supports multiple choice tests and a question item pool to share question items with other authors or for building your own question pool. Assessment is not a typical scenario for a CMS, it is a use case for a LMS like OpenOLAT.

In OpenOLAT you can also configure two sites with permanent content. This is very often used as a simple intranet/extranet solution without the need for an additional CMS. If your emphasis is on elearning rather than static web site content you should consider this path.

This is clearly the most simple solution for your customers as they only have to get familiar with one single system.

Cheers
Florian